# Constraining to release version in Ivy

Tags: ivy

#### Scenario

Our platform module (`PNX`) is released to our local Artifactory server with a SemVersion-like versioning scheme on 4 digits

```
3.x.y.z
```

In particular, `z` is incremented on bugfixes. It is our policy that modules (named e.g. `ARF`, `FTT`, `PGS` etc) take the latest bugfix version of the PNX version they are compiled against. e.g. if `FTT` is compiled after `PNX 3.4.5.7` when building a WAR it must take the latest `3.4.5.x` of PNX, which may be someday `3.4.5.10`.

#### Current release and ivy descriptor

We have released version 3.3.3.0 a few weeks ago and developers are using it happily. Luckily, no blocking bug forced us yet to release the `3.3.3.1`.

Our projects show a `dependencies.xml` file like the following

```
    <dependency org="com.acme"              name="PNX"          rev="${pnx.version}" />
```

where `pnx.version` equals to `3.3.3.+`. According to Ivy's [sub-revision matcher](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/version-matchers.html), the above matches any version equal or subsequent to `3.3.3.0` when it is available, as we like to have.

#### Problem with beta

For development purposes we are starting to release (with `integration` status) betas of our `PNX` module, so that my coworkers can start to test new features or bugfixes in the scope of their module when it comes difficult to test with PNX alone.

Here is what happened. I released a `3.3.3.1-BETA` with `integration` status before the official `3.3.3.1` was ready, and I am also working with `3.5.0.0-BETA` in another project. One day my coworker working at `ARF` module made a release for shipping to production, using `3.3.3.+` revision constraint, but ended up resolving the `3.3.3.1-BETA`!!

### Question time

I would like to understand if and how is it possible to specify a revision constraint in Ivy that takes the lastest **stable** version in a versioning range where only the build number is unknown (take the 3.x.y.z example where 3 is a vanity version number from your perspective).

Ivy offers `latest.release` constraint but it will also match `3.4.x.y` when they are available (and that is what I do **not** want). However, the `+` version matcher matches betas too, and that is still not correct.

[Edit]
Ivy settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<ivysettings>

    <settings defaultResolver="main" />
    <!--Authentication required for publishing (deployment). 'Artifactory Realm' is the realm used by Artifactory so don't change it. -->
    <credentials host="host.acme.com" realm="Artifactory Realm" username="deployment" passwd="deployment123" />
    <resolvers>
        <chain name="main" changingPattern=".*-BETA.*" checkmodified="true">
            <ibiblio name="public" m2compatible="true" root="http://host.acme.com/artifactory/acme-all" />
            <url name="cst" m2compatible="false">
                <artifact pattern="http://host.acme.com/artifactory/acme/[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[module].[ext]" />
                <ivy pattern="http://host.acme.com/artifactory/acme/[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/ivy.xml" />
            </url>
            <url name="cst-integration" m2compatible="false" changingPattern=".*-BETA.*" checkmodified="true">
                <artifact pattern="http://host.acme.com/artifactory/acme-integration/[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[module](-[classifier])-[revision].[ext]" />
                <ivy pattern="http://host.acme.com/artifactory/acme-integration/[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/ivy-[revision].xml" />
            </url>
        </chain>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

Explanation: we have an `acme-all` repository that is a virtual mapping to public Maven (thus using ibiblio), then our internal `acme` and `acme-integration` repos.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to understand that Artifactory's Maven repository layout is not ivy's native format. The [ibiblio resolver](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/resolver/ibiblio.html) is capable of understanding and translating [Maven repository metadata](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-repository-metadata/index.html).

For example the following is the metadata associated with the [log4j module](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/maven-metadata.xml) in Maven central:

```
<metadata modelVersion="1.1.0">
  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  <versioning>
    <latest>1.2.17</latest>
    <release>1.2.17</release>
    <versions>
      <version>1.1.3</version>
      <version>1.2.4</version>
      <version>1.2.5</version>
      ..
      ..
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>20140318154402</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

Note the "latest" and "release" tags? What is your module's metadata showing? I suspect you're discover it's 3.3.3.1-BETA, which would explain your issue.

Ivy's concept of an "integration" release would be implemented in Maven as a Snapshot version.

Finally it's possible to configure the [ibiblio resolver](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/resolver/ibiblio.html) not to use the remote repository metadata:

```
<ibiblio name="MyRepo" m2compatible="true" useMavenMetadata="false" root="http://…" />
```

Generally this rarely needed unless the repo metadata file cannot be relied upon (which is [weirdly common](https://ssinghvi.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/unable-to-retrieve-latest-artifact-from-sonatype-nexus-using-apache-ivy/)).

Comment: My Artifactory server uses Ivy layout and not Maven. In fact, I am not using an ibiblio resolver to access my repositories

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ That would have been helpful to know. Shall I assume you're using the URL resolver instead? How is it configured? If there is a problem resolving an artefact version then it inevitable is down to how the resolver setup.

Comment: Question updated. If you need additional info I will be glad to provide them.